# How to download save Media from oneNote

Tags: windows-10-mobile, music, photos, onenote

I had created a note in my ***OneNote*** which has some photos and recorded audios from my Lumia 640 phone.

Unfortunately, I have deleted photos from my phone but it is save in *OneNote*. Now, I want to download that photos again from note.

In addition, I have also recorded some music in same note, How can I get `.mp3` file of that audio?

Comment: im also after a solution to this however i didn't delete them i took the photos directly into one note to make reference to the photos and they didn't save to my gallery but i want to get the photos out to use them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its easier to download media from OneNote...through your computer. OneNote on the desktop allows you to right click on a media file within the note and choose an option  of downloading the media or, in the case of .mp3 files, to play/preview then

I advise that you open OneNote on your computer, syncronize it, making sure that the same account on your Windows Phone is the same connected on your machine's OneNote app. After doing so, go download the files from any particular note, and save them onto your computer, from where you can transfer to other devices, including your phone, using more conventional methods of transfer like bluetooth, email etc.